# Max value that changes as new data comes in with Python 3.5

Tags: python, max, python-3.5

I am newer to coding and this may have a simple solution, but basically I am trying to record incoming data from sensors connected to an Arduino. For my purposes I would like to not only record the data that is coming in, but also the highest value that the trial had.

The code that I have results in only making the `Max_Force = 0`. My end goal is to have all of the values that I am recording to also save the max value. Then finally linking all of these values to a GUI for easy operator use.

```
import serial
import csv
import time
import numpy as np
import warnings
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports

arduino_ports = [
    p.device
    for p in serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
    if 'Arduino' in p.description
]
if not arduino_ports:
    raise IOError("No Arduino found")
if len(arduino_ports) > 1:
    warnings.warn('Multiple Arduinos found - using the first')

Arduino = serial.Serial(arduino_ports[0])
Arduino.flush()
Arduino.reset_input_buffer()

start_time=time.time()
Distance = 0.5 # This is how long the lever arm is in feet


with open('DynoData.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    outfileWrite = csv.writer(outfile)
    while True:
        while (Arduino.inWaiting()==0):
            pass
        try:
            data = Arduino.readline()
            dataarray = data.decode().rstrip().split(',')
            Arduino.reset_input_buffer()
            Force = round(float(dataarray[0]),3)
            Max_Force = 0
            if Max_Force < Force:
                Max_Force == Force
            else:
                Max_Force == Max_Force

            RPM = round(float (dataarray[1]),3)
            Torque = round(Force * Distance,3)
            HorsePower = round(Torque * RPM / 5252,3)
            Run_Time = round(time.time()-start_time,3)
            print (Force ,",",Max_Force )
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit,IndexError,ValueError):
            pass

        outfileWrite.writerow([Force,",",Max_Force,"lbs", RPM, "RPMs", Torque,"ft-lbs" ,HorsePower ,"HP" ,Run_Time ,"sec" ])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are assigning a variable, you only use 1 equal sign. So `Max_Force == Force` needs to be `Max_Force = Force` and these lines:

```
else:
    Max_Force == Max_Force #there should only be 1 equal sign btw
```

are unnecessary since there is no reason to set a variable to itself.

You also need to move `Max_Force = 0` above the `while True` loop since you are constantly setting `Max_Value` back to 0.

Comment: I have tried this as well and as a result it just makes the Max_Force value always equal the Force value regardless of the previous value of the Force. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that I need to have another variable that I set Max_Force Equal to to get it to not just be the same number for each iteration?

Comment: @MatthewEspindolaMunn: You assign `Max_Force=0` every iteration.  Don’t do that.

Comment: That seemed to have worked. I guess it's the little things, but I suppose if I follow the logic of my original code, it must be comparing the Force value to 0 and it is always larger than 0. Thank you for your help. To the both of you that is!